# How to make attachment in laravel email

Tags: laravel, email, attachment, email-attachments

i try to send email in laravel 5.2 and its works.
my problem is how to convert a view with its data to PDF then attach it to email
i try this

```
$datastd['fname']=$printqu->std_fname;
$datastd['mname']=$printqu->std_mname;
$datastd['lname']=$printqu->std_lname;
$datastd['email']=$printqu->std_email;
$datastd['email']=$printqu->std_email;
$datastd['orgname']=$printqu->name;
$datastd['depname']=$printqu->Dep_Name;




Mail::send('email.train_form',['datastd'=>$datastd], function($mail) use ($datastd){

    $mail->to($datastd['email'],$datastd['fname'],$datastd['mname'],$datastd['lname'],$datastd['orgname'],$datastd['depname'])->attachData($datastd, 'printPreviewm.pdf')->from('everyone@gmail.com')->subject('Training Forms');

});
```

the error is time out
please i need your help in this

Comment: you'll need to use a third party library to convert your documents into PDF, laravel is not going to do that out of the box for you.

Comment: thanx alot Mr Serg.. can you guid me  hot to do that?

Comment: Check out http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html for a simple idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Sorry, your question is based on Laravel 5.2 and my answer is based on Laravel 5.4. As of generating a PDF can still be done with the [DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) package, and the docs for attaching it to a mail can be found in the official Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#attachments)

---

Generating a PDF based on a view template can be easily done by using a package such as [DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) made by Barryvdh

**Generating a PDF** would look something like this

```
$view = View::make('any.view', compact('variable'));
$contents = $view->render();
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML($contents);
$output = $pdf->output();

Storage::put('/folder/your-file.pdf', $output);
```

**Attaching a document to a mail** is pretty simple in Laravel (5.4) [[docs]](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail)

```
// file location
$file = storage_path('app/folder/your-file.pdf');

// return mail with an attachment
return $this->view('emails.confirm')
    ->from('me@stackoverflow.com', 'From')->subject('New mail')
    ->with([
        'name' => $this->data['name'],
    ])->attach($file, [
        'as' => 'File name',
        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
    ]);
```

Comment: your solution was great but with some customizations . thank you man

Answer (score 1):

i try the following

```
$view = View::make('printPreview', compact('printqu','printqu2'));
$contents = $view->render();
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML($contents);
$output = $pdf->output();

Storage::put('app/folderletter/your-file.pdf', $output);

 $datastd['fname']=$printqu->std_fname;
 $datastd['mname']=$printqu->std_mname;
 $datastd['lname']=$printqu->std_lname;
 $datastd['email']=$printqu->std_email;
 $datastd['email']=$printqu->std_email;
 $datastd['orgname']=$printqu->name;
 $datastd['depname']=$printqu->Dep_Name;
$file = storage_path('app/folderletter/your-file.pdf');

   Mail::send('email.train_form',['datastd'=>$datastd], function($mail) use ($datastd,$file){
     //$pdf = PDF::loadView('printPreviewm',['datastd'=>$datastd]);
     $mail->to($datastd['email'],$datastd['fname'],$datastd['mname'],$datastd['lname'],$datastd['orgname'],$datastd['depname'])
     ->from('everyone@gmail.com')->subject('Training Forms')
     ->attach('app/folderletter/your-file.pdf', [
                    'as' => 'name.pdf',
                    'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                ]);
                });
```

i saves the document in Storeag
but also the same
time out!!!!
so the message not sent.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all of you.. i solve it. it was something like this

```
$view = View::make('printPreview', compact('printqu','printqu2'));
$contents = $view->render();
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML($contents);
$output = $pdf->output();

Storage::put('app/folderletter/your-file.pdf', $output);

 $datastd['fname']=$printqu->std_fname;
 $datastd['mname']=$printqu->std_mname;
 $datastd['lname']=$printqu->std_lname;
 $datastd['email']=$printqu->std_email;
 $datastd['email']=$printqu->std_email;
 $datastd['orgname']=$printqu->name;
 $datastd['depname']=$printqu->Dep_Name;

//$file= public_path(). "/app/".$sestest3->dep_path;
$file = storage_path(). "/app/app/folderletter/your-file.pdf";
   Mail::send('email.train_form',['datastd'=>$datastd], function($mail) use ($datastd,$file){
     //$pdf = PDF::loadView('printPreviewm',['datastd'=>$datastd]);
     $mail->to($datastd['email'],$datastd['fname'],$datastd['mname'],$datastd['lname'],$datastd['orgname'],$datastd['depname'])
     ->from('everyone@gmail.com')->subject('Training Forms')
     ->attach($file, [
                    'as' => 'name.pdf',
                    'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                ]);
                });
```